# SBPL Package Relocation

Tags: ros, github, sbpl-lattice-planner, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was wondering where the current sbpl package is located. The link on the sbpl package for fuerte is dead (http://www.ros.org/wiki/sbpl) and the ros-gbp github repository for sbpl has nothing in it (https://github.com/ros-gbp/sbpl-fuerte-release). Also the sbpl github repository linked to from (http://www.sbpl.net/Software) is not a ROS package (https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl).

I am trying to compile and run the sbpl_lattice_planner and I am getting errors saying the sbpl package is not found.

Thanks,
Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57628/sbpl-package-relocation/) by [malvarado](https://answers.ros.org/users/3532/malvarado/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it was previously in arm_navigation, then I would check out the new MoveIt package. Specifically, take a look at https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_planners

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malvarado](https://answers.ros.org/users/3532/malvarado/) on 2013-03-11**:
Thanks. I appears the period got included in your link so it thinks its dead.

**Comment by [malvarado](https://answers.ros.org/users/3532/malvarado/) on 2013-03-24**:
For Fuerte I was able to get sbpl to work checking out the dev branch of https://github.com/sbpl/sbpl which is a ros package unlike the master branch.